# Does return inside an if() which is inside a for() - return from the if() or the for()?

Tags: return

Ok, I'm unsure if my return line will end the for() loop or just the if() question?

Example:

```
for(;;) {
  wait(1);
  if(something) {
    tokens = strTok(something, " ")
    if(tokens.size < 2)
      return;
   }
}
```

I'm guessing that it'll just return from the if(something) question but I just want to be sure...

Comment: Why don't try by yourself and see what happens?

Comment: I assume you're thinking of break, not return.  See sepp2k's answer.

Comment: Among other things, when asking a questions, it is always worth specifying what language it is for (this looks like C or C++, but it could just as well be Java or C# or JavaScript or any of the other several dozen curly braces family languages). Use tags for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In C-like languages, `return` exits the entire function. `break` will exit the innermost loop (`for` `do...while` or `while`)

Answer (score 3):

In all languages I know (except haskell) `return` will return from enclosing function/method, while `break` would "return" from the loop.

Comment: In XQuery and XPath 2.0, `return` is FLWOR keyword which is exactly equivalent to C# LINQ `select` - i.e. what you write as `from x in xs select x` in C#, you'd write as `for $x in $xs return $x` in XQuery.

Answer (score 2):

return in most languages will end the entire method.

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on the particular language but for all the languages I can think of return will return from the current function. FOR() and IF() structures don't usually have return statements.

Answer (score 1):

RETURN is, for all languages I know, "Stop doing what you're doing and exit this function completely".  From your description you apparently don't want RETURN, you want an BREAK or CONTINUE, depending on the language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

This is presumably all inside a function or method; RETURN will exit that function/method.

To give an example of a more procedural setting, in a PHP file a RETURN that isn't in a function will exit the current script file.  (Again, it won't matter if it's inside other blocks.)